# Connecting to invalid output 1 of source node PartitionedCall which has 1 outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use bilinear interpolation in tensorflow, a function is available for this in the Tensorflow Addons library [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/v0.11.2/tensorflow_addons/image/dense_image_warp.py), however it only has Tf2.x support. I need to get this function working in Tf1.15, so I made few small modifications and things seem fine until actually training when it throws this error that I can't understand ([see collab notebook with demo code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Zbe7jqdRbrEsZU3LG322GBBaFPZAcCSB?usp=sharing)). What is this `PartitionedCall`? I tried another simpler model with `conv2D` layers instead of `conv3D` and that doesn't throw such errors, which part of conv3D layers is the culprit here? Also no such error with Tf2 of course, what is causing this?

Suggestions for other ways to get bilinear interpolation working in Tf1.15 should also be helpful. Thanks!